# Writing a template

Tags: c++, templates, typename

I need some help with C++ templates.

The following lines are given:

```
  Array < int, 4, 7 > something1;

  Array < char, 3, 'F' > something2;
```

I have to write a template for this, and I tried something like:

```
template < typename T1, int a1, typename T2 >

class Array
{

.....

};
```

But I am pretty sure this won't be the correct way, I'm not really familiar with templates yet. I can't figure out how to handle this, because when creating "something1", the third parameter is an integer, and at "something2" the third parameter is a character.
What should be the correct solution?

Comment: Is this an academic exercise or are you re-inventing the [Standard Library](http://cppreference.com/)? It's okay if this is an exercise, but you should be more specific in your question so your intent is better understood.

Comment: It is an exercise. Sorry for my silly question, I did not realise at first it is so simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Template parameters can be types or non-types.  In the realm of non-types, integrals are commonly used.  Both `char` and `int` are integral types.

```
template <typename T1, int A1, char C1>
class Array 
{
  // ...
};
```

Comment: The third parameter should also be typenamed, in his example it's a int or a char

Comment: @JamilSeaidoun: The third parameter *can't* be a `typename` -- neither `7` nor `'F'` are types.  However `7` can be an initializer for a `char`, as with `char c = 7;`, so that's why I specified `char` for the third parameter.

Comment: fair enough, sorry for some reason my mind went to java and though there's autoboxing for integral types, but you can use 'class' instead of typename and the compiler will replace it appropriately

Comment: What I didn't understand was that how to make a template, so that I can create "something1" and "something2", and the third parameters are elements of different types, but now I see that I can assign an integer to a char.